# Oracle delete performance

Tags: performance, oracle, foreign-keys

Say I have two tables:

```
create table parent (
  id number not null,
  constraint parent_pk primary key(id),
)

create table child (
  id number not null,
  parent_id number not null,
  constraint child_pk primary key(id),
  constraint child_fk1 foreign key(parent_id)
    references parent(id)
)
```

The parent table is big, say, 3 millions records. Now I run delete statement:

```
delete from parent; //even without where clause
```

Could you please explain what actually happens when this statement is executed? Where is no "ON DELETE CASCADE" option specified, as far as I understand it means that delete from parent table should fail if the child table contains references to parent id. So this means that before deleting the row from parent table Oracle should check if any child records exists. But this is really extremely slow - it's row-by-row delete.

Am I correct? If not, please explain how Oracle works when deleting from parent table and check whether there are no orphans left in child table?

Comment: I think you are right. It is a row-by-row check. ON DELETE CASCADE should not fail, though, but delete child rows as well.

Comment: Does not this mean that ON DELETE CASCADE will perform roughly the same as without this option? (taking in account that there is no table that references child table)

Comment: When you say "But this is really extremely slow - it's row-by-row delete." do you mean you have run a test case and it is *really slow*?  Or just that you imagine that would be the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a test.  My PARENT table has 100000 rows.  Against an empty CHILD table (with an index on PARENT_ID) deletion takes this long:

```
SQL> set timing on
SQL> delete from parent;

100000 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:00:07.24
SQL>
```

Let's insert some rows into CHILD.  This will generate one row for every row in PARENT

```
SQL> insert into child
  2  select level, level from dual
  3  connect by level <= 100000;


100000 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.21
SQL>
```

If we delete from parent now, it fails instantly.

```
SQL> delete from parent;
delete from parent
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (APC.CHILD_FK1) violated - child record found


Elapsed: 00:00:00.14
SQL>
```

Whereas, if we have every record in CHILD point to just one record in PARENT it takes a bit longer...

```
SQL> update child set parent_id=99999;

100000 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:09.65
SQL> commit;

SQL> delete from parent;
delete from parent
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (APC.CHILD_FK1) violated - child record found


Elapsed: 00:00:07.32
```

Wallclock timings are notoriously unreliable, but that looks like roughly the same amount of time.  And as it happens, the time to delete the PARENT table without foreign key dependencies is in the same ballpark:

```
SQL> drop table child;

Table dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.29
SQL> delete from parent;

100000 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:00:06.54
SQL>
```

So, basically, there is little or no overhead to check the foreign key constraint

There is a proviso: this is true *providing the foreign key column is indexed*.  I dropped the CHILD_FK1_I index, and the `delete from parent` statement still hasn't finished in the time it's taken me to type up this response i.e. about ten minutes.

Comment: Oh, that's great. Could you please also take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902473/oracle-bottom-up-delete)?

Answer (score 1):

Because your child table has no index on parent_id, oracle is forced to do a full scan every time it needs to check for existence of children. Another problem that the lack of this index could raise when you plan to do this with multiple processes is contention. Without the parent_id being indexed, the child table will get a table lock, where normally only a row would be locked.

Besides that, giving the database the order to delete a row is the worst possible command to execute. If you look to what happens underwater (undo, redo etc.) it is amazing that it all goes that quick ...

Comment: Ok, for example i've created index for parent_id. How fast will Oracle determine whether no child rows reference parent row in this case?

Comment: @andrershov it will be pretty fast, although if you have to do this for lots of rows you might consider disabling the constraint and enabling it afterwards.

Comment: it will check for existence of the parent_id in the index. Pretty quick, depending on the hardware involved. If you want to do bulk deletes, disabling the contraints will be way faster but prevents multi user operation.

Comment: worst possible command: Oracle has to keep everyting logged and reversable by maintaining undo and redo records, just to see that when it's ready, the data is gone.... A logical delete can be quicker since it has less overhead.

Comment: How could you explain that the performance of delete from parent is really slow, even if there are no records in the child table? I've doubled checked that no triggers and locks on parent table is hold

Comment: How long does it take to run a count(*) from the child table? If that is consuming time, I guess that the child table has had lots of rows before. Those rows are deleted but the HWM is still far away. If that is the case, truncate the child table. Also check locks for the child table....